# File format for CVs for software freelance jobs

Tags: portfolio, resume

I've used Word for the last 15 years. I have to crank up a Windows XP virtual machine to run it. I don't own a more up-to-date copy of Windows, since I focus heavily on Unix development. I only use Word because it seemed to be necessary to keep recruitment agencies and HR departments happy.

Do you think it is best to submit CVs in Word, PDF, or something else? Is it time for me to give up Word and solely use PDF?

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this isn't about freelancing

Comment: People on these sites are so damned keen to off-topic things. Its a CV for freelancing work. Where else do you suggest that I post the question?

Comment: Hmm.. never needed a cv for *any* freelance work.

Comment: Why not OpenOffice/LibreOffice/GoogleDocs in lieu of Microsoft Word?

Comment: Have you ever created a document in OO then opened it in Word? It usually comes out a complete mess. Another reason for switching to PDF is that I can create a beautiful document using LaTeX and be sure that it will remain beautiful all the way to the hiring managers inbox. Word emulators are completely out of the question for me.

Comment: HR Departments don't care how "spiffy" your PDF looks. They only care that it won't go through their Microsoft Word Macros. Resumes/CVs aren't all about how *you* want it to look. If it's a problem for HR... it's tossed or filed away to be forgotten.

Comment: I suspect a PDF produced by LaTeX would be cleaner that one produced by Word, when it comes to extacting the text? But yes, this is part of the reason for asking because I worry that a PDF might not go through these tools as easily as Word, or is that not the case?
OO -> Word could also be a disaster in that regard. Try it, you'll see what a mess the Word document comes out as.

Comment: As far as I can tell all HR departments care about is if your CV gets a good score when word matched against the job spec. Yes, I am familiar with this game. But I still want a good looking copy to end up in the hiring managers hands, that does make a difference.

Comment: @scott, I've had to submit a cv for larger freelancing jobs many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Portable Document Format* is actually the best format to submit any documentation. It guarantees the document will be received with the exact formatting. Word documents will render diferently depending on the application the receiver uses (ie, MS Word vs LibreOffice).

**EDIT**: As noted by Peter on comments, it also guarantees it will be exactly as you planed to be if receiver prints the document

Comment: To add, if they print it out, you want it be exactly as you planned it to be.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal answer is PDF, however in my experience most agents want you to send a word file anyway.

What I do is I create my CV in Word and then save it out in both formats. I send Word files to agents and PDFs to direct clients.

Comment: Thanks, I think I may go the other way; LaTeX to produce the PDF, but then cut and paste the text into a very simple Word document with no fancy formatting for the situation where I have to.